# How to create draggable mask?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Let say I have one UIView and one image mask. We must be able to drag the mask so its position will be updated each time the user drag it. I know how to mask an image, I also know how to drag the image but I can't combine both of it. Can anyone show me?

Answer (score 0):

did you consider to use a container uiview which holds your other uiview, masks & images? Then the user would just drag the container.